# Regex whole line

Tags: c#, regex

I have this regex to read all lines after the value Description:

```
var descriptionMatches =
  Regex.Matches(source, @"\b(?<key>Description)\s*(?<value>\w+)");
```

The problem is, the returned value is only the first word, not the whole line.

What I'm missing,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `\w+` to be `.+`. This will match all characters instead of just a series word characters (which does not include whitespace).

Also, if you want `.` to match newlines (you indicate that you want to match all lines after the description), then you must use the `RegexOptions.Singleline` option:

```
var descriptionMatches =
  Regex.Matches(source, @"\b(?<key>Description)\s*(?<value>.+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```